# Want to remove border and AnchorPoint of label

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a label that will resize as user want to by user touches,i have done it using class from [this project](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView) from github.

But it is displaying anchorpoint and border at label,i want that when use click background than this anchor point and border will removed..hlp.

**EDIT**

UserResizableView.h file

```
@interface UserResizableView : UIView {
    SPGripViewBorderView *borderView;
    UIView *contentView;
    CGPoint touchStart;
    CGFloat minWidth;
    CGFloat minHeight;

    BOOL shouldDrawAnchorPoint;
    // Used to determine which components of the bounds we'll be modifying, based upon where the user's touch started.
    SPUserResizableViewAnchorPoint anchorPoint;

    id <UserResizableViewDelegate> delegate;
}
```

UserResizableView.m file

```
@implementation SPGripViewBorderView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Clear background to ensure the content view shows through.
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(shouldDrawAnchorPoint)
    {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // (1) Draw the bounding box.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectInset(self.bounds, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2));
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // (2) Calculate the bounding boxes for each of the anchor points.
    CGRect upperLeft = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect upperRight = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, 0.0, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect lowerRight = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect lowerLeft = CGRectMake(0.0, self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect upperMiddle = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, 0.0, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect lowerMiddle = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect middleLeft = CGRectMake(0.0, (self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
    CGRect middleRight = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, (self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);

    // (3) Create the gradient to paint the anchor points.
    CGFloat colors []= { 
        0.4, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 
       0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
    };
    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, NO, NULL, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;


    // (4) Set up the stroke for drawing the border of each of the anchor points.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5), 1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    // (5) Fill each anchor point using the gradient, then stroke the border.
    CGRect allPoints[8] = { upperLeft, upperRight, lowerRight, lowerLeft, upperMiddle, lowerMiddle, middleLeft, middleRight };
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        CGRect currPoint = allPoints[i];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, currPoint);
        CGContextClip(context);
        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currPoint), CGRectGetMinY(currPoint));
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currPoint), CGRectGetMaxY(currPoint));
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectInset(currPoint, 1, 1));
    }

    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    shouldDrawAnchorPoint = YES;
    // Notify the delegate we've begun our editing session.
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:self];
    }

    [borderView setHidden:NO];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    anchorPoint = [self anchorPointForTouchLocation:[touch locationInView:self]];

    // When resizing, all calculations are done in the superview's coordinate space.
    touchStart = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    if (![self isResizing]) {
        // When translating, all calculations are done in the view's coordinate space.
        touchStart = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;
    // Notify the delegate we've ended our editing session.
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewDidEndEditing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewDidEndEditing:self];
        [borderView setHidden:YES];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        anchorPoint = [self anchorPointForTouchLocation:[touch locationInView:self]];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;
    // Notify the delegate we've ended our editing session.
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewDidEndEditing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewDidEndEditing:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in **SPGripViewBorderView** interface add a boolean "shouldDrawAnchorPoint" :

```
@interface SPGripViewBorderView : UIView
{
  BOOL shouldDrawAnchorPoint;
}

@property(nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL shouldDrawAnchorPoint;

@end
```

Now in **SPGripViewBorderView** implementation set the boolean attribute by default and add an instruction in the drawRect method to only draw when shouldDrawAnchorPoint is true :

```
@implementation SPGripViewBorderView

@synthesize shouldDrawAnchorPoint;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Clear background to ensure the content view shows through.
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if(shouldDrawAnchorPoint)
    {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        // (1) Draw the bounding box.
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
        CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectInset(self.bounds, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2));
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        // (2) Calculate the bounding boxes for each of the anchor points.
        CGRect upperLeft = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect upperRight = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, 0.0, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect lowerRight = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect lowerLeft = CGRectMake(0.0, self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect upperMiddle = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, 0.0, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect lowerMiddle = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect middleLeft = CGRectMake(0.0, (self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);
        CGRect middleRight = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, (self.bounds.size.height - kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize)/2, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize, kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize);

        // (3) Create the gradient to paint the anchor points.
        CGFloat colors [] = {
        0.4, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
        };
        CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

        // (4) Set up the stroke for drawing the border of each of the anchor points.
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
        CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5), 1);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

        // (5) Fill each anchor point using the gradient, then stroke the border.
        CGRect allPoints[8] = { upperLeft, upperRight, lowerRight, lowerLeft, upperMiddle, lowerMiddle, middleLeft, middleRight };
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            CGRect currPoint = allPoints[i];
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, currPoint);
            CGContextClip(context);
            CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currPoint), CGRectGetMinY(currPoint));
            CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currPoint), CGRectGetMaxY(currPoint));
            CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectInset(currPoint, 1, 1));
        }
        CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}
@end
```

Now in the **SPUserResizableView** implementation set the boolean to true or false (depending on the user starts using the screen or ends using screen) in the following methods :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    borderView.shouldDrawAnchorPoint = YES;
    [borderView needsDisplay];

    // Notify the delegate we've begun our editing session.
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:self];
    }

    [borderView setHidden:NO];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    anchorPoint = [self anchorPointForTouchLocation:[touch locationInView:self]];

    // When resizing, all calculations are done in the superview's coordinate space.
    touchStart = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    if (![self isResizing]) {
        // When translating, all calculations are done in the view's coordinate space.
        touchStart = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    borderView.shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;
    [borderView needsDisplay];

    // Notify the delegate we've ended our editing session.
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewDidEndEditing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewDidEndEditing:self];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    borderView.shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;
    [borderView needsDisplay];

    // Notify the delegate we've ended our editing session.
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewDidEndEditing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewDidEndEditing:self];
    }
}
```

The thing is to add a boolean value and when the user tap the screen (touchesBegan) set the boolean to true and when the user stop using his fingers on screen (touchesEnded), set the boolean to false. And draw the anchor point only if the boolean value is true.

Comment: it will just remove anchorpoint but i want that when user touch background than it will hide.

Comment: I want to display anchorpoint but when user want to resize it .

Comment: it display error at initwithframe andin i have seted shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;

Comment: it sais undeclared identifier used 'shouldDrawAnchorPoint'

Comment: Did you add "BOOL shouldDrawAnchorPoint;" in the SPUserResizableView.h ? (in the interface)

Comment: yes,but in your code it seems that shouldDrawAnchorPoint = NO;  is called in SPGripViewBorderView,and for SPGripViewBorderView it is undeclared so it is displaying error.

Comment: So in fact you have to add a boolean value in SPGripViewBorderView and set it to true or false, depending on the user touche the screen or net. See my edit for more information.

Comment: ok,i have done that mistake,now its working really great thanx.